# How to get rid of icons in extjs tree

Tags: javascript, extjs, tree, treepanel

I would like to get rid of the icons in an extjs tree. Instead i would like to set all the nodes that have children in bold.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

ExtJS relies on CSS for styling, so the easiest way to remove the icons is to create a CSS rule that overrides one provided by Ext.

This will do the job :

```
.x-tree-icon { display: none !important; }
```

Add a class with the `extraCls` config option or use the component ID to qualify the rule if necessary.

As for the bold text, there doesn't seem to be a way using just CSS, so you could listen to the afterRender event of the tree view, though that won't be enough if you add nodes dynamically.

Comment: assuming of course it's the only way you want trees in your whole application... you might want to add a class to your tree panel , then reference specifically in that case.

Answer (score 3):

In the column definition:

```
columns: [{
    xtype: 'treecolumn',
    text: 'Task',
    iconCls: '', // This property to get rid of tree icon
    width: 200,
    sortable: true,
    dataIndex: 'someStringIdentifier',
    locked: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below my solution with ExtJS 6.5 that brings 2 advantages:

- to focus on certain types of nodes only
- to avoid the space between the trigger and the text

I define in the **Model** a calculated `iconCls` returning a custom css class:

```
{
    name: 'iconCls',
    calculate: function (data) {
        return 'uw-shrink-icon';
    }
}
```

Then in the sass file I take advantage of the native `x-tree-icon-custom` css class to set the width to 0:

```
.x-tree-icon-custom.uw-shrink-icon {
    background-image: none;
    width:0px;
}
```